# Yandex map API. Отображение карты при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Использую готовый пример из yandex map api с подсказками. Но карта появляется только тогда, когда я введу в строку поиска какой-то адрес и нажму искать. Как сделать что бы по умолчанию на странице отображалась карта с координатами? Полагаю надо указать что то здесь (указал кусок кода на скриншоте):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В целом, карта вставляется вот таким образом:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.684758, 37.738521],
    zoom: 11
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });

  myMap.geoObjects
    .add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.684758, 37.738521], {
      preset: 'islands#icon',
      iconColor: '#0095b6'
    }));
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!--
    Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
    Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=60445215-6d3a-4f88-87fe-8d52b72e5bc9"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[На JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shchedrin/1eoty9r2/3/).